# regex doesn't capture all groups

Tags: python, regex, xml

```
   <name>name for the group</name><description>server-description</description><resource>10.1.1.1:*</resource><resource>10.1.1.2:*</resource><resource>10.1.1.3:*</resource><apply>selected</apply><network-connect-acl><<name>name2</name><description>description2/description><resource>10.2.2.0/26:*</resource><apply>selected</apply>
```

I have converted an XML file to string as above value and trying to catch multiple occurrences of `<resource>ABC</resource>` I have the following regex
defined in python3

```
regex = re.compile(r'(<name>.*?</name>)(.*?)(<resource>.*?</resource>)+')
print(regex.findall(string))
```

but instead of catching all three occurrences, it only catches the first one:

```
('<name>name for the group</name>', '<description>server-
description</description>', '<resource>10.1.1.1:*</resource>')
```

I would like the regex to catch the string in between  and  tags. If we take the string above as sample, I expect to catch it something like this;

```
<name>name for the group</name><resource>10.1.1.1:*</resource><resource>10.1.1.2:*</resource><resource>10.1.1.3:*</resource><name>name2</name><description>description2/description><resource>10.2.2.0/26:*</resource>
```

In doing so, I will group "name" element with its associated resource elements so that the first tuple matched by this regex will contain this:

```
('<name>nameforthegroup</name>','<resource>10.1.1.1:*</resource>
<resource>10.1.1.2:*</resource><resource>10.1.1.3:*</resource>')
```

and second tuple and so fort will be like this

```
('<name>name2</name>','<resource>10.2.2.0/26:*</resource>)
```

The file contains hundreds of records like this but when I run the code I get something like this:

```
[('<name>nameforthegroup</name>', '<description>server-description</description>', '<resource>10.1.1.1:*</resource>'), ('<name>name2</name>', '<description>description2/description>', '<resource>10.2.2.0/26:*</resource>')]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is nice that you use code snippet, but first you should show explicitely not only regex and wished result (you haven't it well, too), but the text to be matched.

Comment: thank you , sorry for the bad entry. I have updated it to give more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a question mark (`?`) after `(<name>.*?</name>)` to make sure it can appear 0 or 1 time or an asterisk (`*`) for more than one time (depending on the input).

```
re.compile(r'(<name>.*?</name>)(.*?)(<resource>.*?</resource>)<apply>')
```

This will let the regex capture the extra resources.

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxtdJf/2)

If you dont need the description you can just never capture it:

```
re.compile('(<name>.*?</name>).*?(<resource>.*?</resource>)<apply>')
```

Comment: but this also displays for example "<apply>selected</apply>" which I don't want. If I change the resource regex to "(<resource>.+?</resource>)" this time, I only get one resource not all of the resources.

Comment: @tirexxerit, no, it never captures `<apply>selected</apply>`.

Comment: @tirexxerit, Oh, you updated the input, I didn't noticed. edited the regex, should be ok now.

Comment: thanks, with <apply> it matches but I was thinking that grouping will already help me catch all resources without having to type <apply> but apparently it isn't the case. Thank you!